# On mac, how to add path to environment variable?

Tags: macos, gcc

I'm using opencv on mac, every time I compile the program, I have to type:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib main.cpp
```

What can I do to avoid typing -I and -L params?

Comment: You don't need either of these - gcc automatically searches these paths by default - just type `g++ main.cpp ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS=-I /usr/local/include -O3 -DSOMETHING
LDFLAGS=-L /usr/local/lib
LIBS=-lwhatever

main: main.o
    $(LD) -o $@ $* $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
```

And then just type `make` at the command prompt:

```
$ make
```

Comment: `CCFLAGS` should be `CXXFLAGS` for C++ files, and `LIBS` should be `LDLIBS`. If you do that then you don't even need rules for `main.o` and `main`, the implicit rules will be fine

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks; actually it should have been `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: yeah I didn't notice it was a C++ file. N.B. LIBS is still wrong, and you still don't need the targets

Comment: @JonathanWakely Well, "wrong" is a bit strong a word isn't it?  That type of Makefile has always worked fine for me...

Comment: @JonathanWakely That's me! :D

Answer (score 0):

trojanfoe is almost right, but the makefile doesn't use the conventional names. If it did, it would be even simpler:

```
CXXFLAGS=-I /usr/local/include -O3 -DSOMETHING
LDFLAGS=-L /usr/local/lib
LDLIBS=-lwhatever
```

With that makefile you can just type `make main` and make will use its implicit rules for compiling a C++ file